# Python For loop with increment

Tags: python

I am trying to increment the value in for loop, By using for with range.
But every time it is iterating one by one. Suggest how can I proceed with this.

```
max1=0
newList=[] 
k=1
for i in range(0,len(arr),k):
    count1=0
    count1 = arr.count(arr[i])
    print(arr[i]," count is  ",count1)
    if count1>max1:
        max1=count1
        newList.clear()
        newList.insert(0,arr[i])
    elif count1==max1 and arr[i] not in newList:
        max1=count1
        newList.append(arr[i])
    k = count1
    print(i," has to skip records for ",k)
```

Comment: And you want it incremented by?

Comment: And would you happen differently ? different increment : change k

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: A `range` always has a fixed interval. If you want to update your increment during the loop, you can't use a `range`. You could use a while loop.

Comment: What exactly is this loop supposed to do? There's almost certainly a more expressive way of accomplishing it than C-style index wrangling.

Comment: Changing `k` in the body of the loop doesn't affect the `range` object, which is created before the loop begins. You can write a `while` loop instead that explicitly increments `i` in the body of the loop, but again, there is probably a more natural way of doing whatever it is this loop is supposed to do.

Comment: I have a sorted list [1,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,7,7,7,7]
I want to find the small number which is repeated most times.
In the above list both 4 and 7 repeated 4 times. Since 4 is the smallest number output should be 4.
In the above code in for loop I am finding the count of each element and adding it to newList if the element is present in loop more times. So after adding to the list I dont want to find the count of the same number again so I want to skip the elements by count1 times. So that for loop execution will be less. But I am not able to increment it by k=count1 times

Comment: Check the answer. Have you tried with numpy's arange()?

Comment: Tried with while loop, It is working fine. Thanks all:)

Answer (score 1):

**Use numpy’s arange()** function to generate the range for float numbers in Python.

Syntax of numpy’s arange() function:

```
arange (start, stop, step, dtype)
```

If dtype is not given, infer the data type from the other input arguments.

Example:

```
import numpy

for i in numpy.arange(0, 1, 0.1):
    print(i, end=', ')
```

Comment: Thanks used while loop and working fine. Thanks for response:)

Comment: You can also create a list of elements using numpy.linspace or similar.